# Why Is Django Not Serving My Static Folder In Development?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to serve some files from the static folder so a js script that runs in one of my templates can require it. Unfortunately, it seems to be picking which files to serve. (or something) It is not serving my js file, breaking my app.

Another problem is that sometimes the favicon becomes missing before the first request is cached. I’ve noticed before in a deployed version of this app that I had to refresh the page after the first load. This is the output from the first request in the current development version:

Here is the output from the first request:

```
(python terminal output from the first request) 
[12/Dec/2020 07:05:49] "GET /requestmap/ HTTP/1.1" 200 399
[12/Dec/2020 07:05:49] "GET /static/dbapi/js/main.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1788
Not Found: /favicon.ico
[12/Dec/2020 07:05:49] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 5553

(python console output from the first request)
http://localhost:8000/static/dbapi/js/main.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

...and after refresh:

```
(python terminal output from the second request)
[12/Dec/2020 07:11:28] "GET /requestmap/ HTTP/1.1" 200 399
[12/Dec/2020 07:11:28] "GET /static/dbapi/js/main.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1788

(chrome console log from the second request):
GET http://localhost:8000/static/dbapi/js/main.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

When I get the admin page all of the CSS and images seem to load fine, but any file that I try to access from the static folder returns a 404 -- including /static/dbapi/js/main.js. (shown in the output messages)

I noticed that my static directory has a rest_framework directory and that is where it seems to be loading the static files from, but if thats what it’s doing now, (I can’t remember how to check that) it doesn’t make any sense to me because I have defined static defined in settings.py: STATIC_URL = '/static/'

settings.py:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
SECRET_KEY = 'gqi&yz3fmq(r-ode(=wd*ey+z0nojx7yrb^v&%6^5sf+(077_m'
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '127.0.0.1']
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'coordinates',
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 10
}

MIDDLEWARE = [
  'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'dbapi.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Directory structure is: dbapi/static/js/main.js

There may be more than one problem here but I can't seem to sort it out. It almost seems to be half serving files and half not but I can't make much out if it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
http://localhost:8000/static/main.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

This tells me that your static files are misplaced or misreferenced in your template

It should be:

```
http://localhost:8000/static/yourappname/js/main.js
```

Make sure in your template, you are referencing it as:

```
{% static 'yourappname/js/main.js' %}
```

You should put your js file in

`yourappname` folder ---> `static` folder ----> `yourappname` folder ---> `js` folder ---> main.js

Comment: I am confused about why the url you gave me has static as a parent directory yet it is contained in the yourappname folder.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to finish that but I forget that enter doesn't add a line in these. I meant to ask if the settings.py was correct with the path '/static/' and was hoping we could clarify why the order you mentioned is correct. I really appreciate your patience because that baffles me.

Comment: Hey wouldn't that mean that on deploy my entire app files can be accessed?

Comment: I believe I made all the changes you recommended, sir, but it is still giving the same results. Thanks for answering though. (Also, I made the changes in the edit)

Comment: same thing my friend. I don't know what else to do except or start over.